# ASP.NET MVC 3: Are multiple nested Views with @section not supported in @RenderSection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my setup in ASP.NET MVC 3:
Master Page --(RenderBody)-> Index View --(Html.Action)-> Partial View.

The Master Page has a `@RenderSection` and the Partial View has a `@section` block but the content isn't being included on the Master Page. I can, however, put the `@section` block on the Index View and that works. Are multi-nested Sections not supported in MVC 3? I really don't want to move the section block up a level but will if there is no other way.

And just FYI this particular RenderSection is at the bottom of the Master Page for including JavaScript blocks. If a partial view needs to execute some script it can include the @section block to keep everything organized.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use @section in a partial view.  You can have nested layouts, but not partials.